# "In library, there is no package called ..." even though I have installed the package

Tags: r, package

I installed R 3.2.3 and RStudio. I then proceeded to install the packages. The first package I tried to install was the "devtools" package. It popped up a message saying since lib is unspecified, would I like to install it at "C:/..". I continued and the packages were installed. But now, I am unable to access them. I changed the path to where the package is installed using .libPaths . But still whenever I write the command require(devtools), it comes up with the following error : Warning message:

In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘devtools’

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It should ask you to write to `/user/R/` folder and this should be automatically added to the path which is searched when loading packages, no need to touch the `.libPaths`.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik , it asked me to write to users/hd/R/ , and it did. But the problem is whenever I try to access it using require(devtools), it gives the warning mentioned in the question

Comment: What does `.libPaths()` produce?

Comment: From what I read, it changes the path to the library containing the packages.

Comment: As @RomanLuštrik asks: what does `.libPaths()` produce? If you call it with no arguments it lists the paths that are checked by R, so you can see where it looks for packages.